# List all sub-packages of a namespace package

Tags: python, setuptools, namespace-package

Python has the ability to create a [namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/). How do you get a list of installed packages under a namespace?

i.e. something like:

```
import namespace_package
dir(namespace_pageage)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-namespace-packages):

```
import pkgutil

list(
    pkgutil.iter_modules(
        namespace_package.__path__,
        namespace_package.__name__ + "."
    )
)
```

Note that this will *not* return (sub-)namespace packages within the main namespace package (i.e. if you have nested namespace packages).

Comment: Mhhh, any idea how to solve this for nested namespace packages as well? I guess one could cook up some self made thing with iterating over the list of paths of the namespace package and recurse into subnamespace packages ... But if there is a ready thing in `pkgutil` it would be much cleaner :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [find_packages](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) function from `setuptools`. This function is often used in `setup.py` files but you can use it for other purposes too.

```
# find the folder of the package
from pathlib import Path
package_root_folder = Path(namespace_package.__file__).parent

# for that folder, detect all Python packages inside
from setuptools import find_packages
all_packages = find_packages(str(package_root_folder))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on pure namespace projects.  `namespace_project.__file__ is None` returns `True`

Comment: What do you mean by 'pure namespace projects'?  You do need to have an `__init__.py` file in there, and then `namespace_package.__file__` is definitely not `None`.

Comment: Namespace packages **do not** require a `__init__.py` file, as they can group together subpackages from multiple points in the filesystem. [PEP420](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) calls them *Implicit Namespace Packages* and [Python packaging guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) calls them *Native namespace packages*.

Comment: Setuptools provides another method called `find_namespace_packages` that one might leverage. I'm not sure under which revision this became accessible.

Comment: @florisla indeed, pep420 states "Namespace packages cannot contain `__init__.py`" and from experience you can get in a real mess if you add one in.